# removing all elements of Joint JS in one on click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jointjs

I noticed that JointJS links can be removed by hovering over them and clicking the big red X that appears. But I was wondering if it is possible remove all the elements on one on click event?

```
    ButtonClick(function(){

// whats the code here??

    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep a track of all the `id`s that you are creating.

Removing an element when you know a `id` is as simple as:

```
graph.getCell(cellID).remove();
```

Just loop over all your `id`s and remove them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Just use clear():

```
graph.clear();
```

Comment: Before anyone chooses to [recommend deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11118854) of this post, this is a valid attempted answer. This post should not have been flagged and should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)